# etwas in dem Park bestellen vs etwas in den Park bestellen

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

> Lass uns doch eine Pizza **in *den* Park** bestellen.

Why did we use the accusative case in this example instead of the dative? Shouldn't it be ***im Park** bestellen* because we are in the park already?

Or is it because the pizza will be **delivered** to us?

I'm really confused by this.

Comment: It's also possible to say: Lass uns im Park eine Pizza in den Park bestellen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you talk about a place, you have to use dative case. But if you talk about a direction, then is has to be accusative case.

**An example:**

- accusative case (direction)

  > Ich gehe in das Haus.
  > I walk into the house.

  I was outside before and now I am inside. I talk about the direction of my movement.
- dative case (place)

  > Ich gehe in dem Haus.
  > I walk in (inside) the house.

  I am inside the house all the time and I walk around inside the house without entering or leaving it. I talk about the place where I perform my movement.

**Now about your pizza:**

- dative case (place)

  > Ich bestelle eine Pizza im (=in dem) Park.
  > I order a pizza in the park.

  I am in the park and while I am there, I order a pizza. I do not tell where the person is who should receive the pizza, and I do not talk about the location of the pizzeria. The receiver of the pizza could be me, but it could be anybody else, inside the park or also outside the park. Maybe I am in the Central Park in New York and I call a pizzeria in Paris and order a pizza for a friend in Paris. I do not talk about from where to where pizza shall move. I just talk about then place where I am when I call the pizzeria.
- accusative case (direction)

  > Ich bestelle eine Pizza in den Park.
  > I oder a pizza into the park.

  I do not tell where I am. I can by anywhere, even on another continent. I just oder a pizza for someone in the park, and I know that the pizzeria is outside the park. So, I know this pizza has to move from outside the park into it. I talk about the direction of the movement of the pizza.

Answer (score 3):

Dativ is used for location. You use it to express *where you are* when you place the order:

> eine Pizza *zu Hause* / *am Strand* / *auf dem Schiff* / ***im Park*** bestellen
>
> <sup>(to order a pizza *at home* / *on the beach* / *on board* / ***in the park***)</sup>

Akkusativ is used for direction. You use it to express *where to deliver* what you ordered:

> eine Pizza *nach Hause* / *an den Strand* / *auf das Schiff* / ***in den Park*** bestellen
>
> <sup>(to order a pizza (for delivery) *home* / *to the beach* / *to the ship* / ***to the park***)</sup>

Both can be combined, for example:

> Lass uns *zu Hause* eine Pizza *in den Park* bestellen.
>
> <sup>(Let's order a pizza *to the park* *at home*.)</sup>